# How to Define Default Spotify Account for Google Home?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

We have a number of smart speakers around the house connected to Google Home.

We have multiple Spotify accounts running under their Premium Family Plan.

One of our Spotify accounts is the "house" account that we set up for playing music around the house. However family members might also cast Spotify from their devices/ accounts.

I'm sure I went into the Google Home app & set our "house" account as the connected Spotify account.

But when my kid says "Hey Google play Minecraft music" to a smart spearker it plays from my Spotify account.

This means I can be listening to my own Spotify music on a device & it will suddenly stop & say that it's playing "Minecraft Creeper Polka Knees Up 3 Hour Marathon" on the smart speaker.

How do I stop this? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Is this of any help in your situation ? It seems that if you can have google home recognize who's asking and setup some things around this, it can work. sometimes ! maybe ! https://community.spotify.com/t5/Accounts/Family-plan-and-Google-Home-cannot-play-in-multiple-devices-at/m-p/4380438/highlight/true#M1482673